# How to plot loss and accuracy graphs using TensorFlow Lite

Tags: python, plot, training-data

I would like to plot the accuracy and loss graphs of a model trained using TensorFlow Lite. Unlike a Keras model there is no `model.fit()` method used but instead `image_classifier.create()` was used to train the model. Hence, I am unsure of how to plot the graphs. If I use `loss_train = model.history['train_loss']`, I get the error `TypeError: 'History' object is not subscriptable`. I have exactly followed [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification?hl=zh-cn) documentation to write my code and would like to know how I can now plot the graphs. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is quite an old question but the answer may be helpful for someone else.
Please run the following first:

```
model.train(
        train_data,
        validation_data=validation_data,
        hparams=None,
        steps_per_epoch=None)
```

then

```
acc = model.history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = model.history.history['val_accuracy']
loss = model.history.history['loss']
val_loss = model.history.history['val_loss']
epochs_range = range(no_epochs)
```

then use same code as for tenstoflow examples of plotting metrics vs. epochs plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Accuracy')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
plt.show()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey there! I don't have the code anymore to test and run but thanks for answering.